# Google Chrome Dev Tools width is different from window.innerWidth

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, width, responsive

How can I make Google Chrome Dev Tools width the same as `window.innerWidth`

PS: `window.screen.width` solved my problem

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Where is this `getCurrentPage` used and where is it shown in the screenshot?

Comment: I want to achieve correct displaying of pages when resizing. `getCurrentPage` and `getTotalPage` are used in `class` to render current and total page. Problem is that I can't figure out if I white correct `if` condition it shows wrong pages when I resize it. On image I show width 1250. Pages must be `1-5` instead of `1-4` because `else if (width > 1079) return totalSlides / 4;`

Comment: Where do you get that `width` from, which is used in your methods? The width shown in the screenshot is the viewport width.

Comment: For debugging reasons, add `console.log(width)` to the beginning of your methods.

Comment: From `window` object

Comment: There are so many confusing things here. What's the reasoning behind this expression? `Math.ceil((currSlide - 1) / perPage) + 1`

Comment: So I have `console.log(width)` and it shows me different width. Not that one which I enter in the browser.  `Math.ceil((currSlide - 1) / perPage) + 1` this is used to `ceil` page numbers. page numbers are float numbers here. I don't know why. I am a Intern and started working 1 week ago :D I still don't understand many things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241425/discussion-between-alex-gru-and-el1oz).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ..... I had a js function that styles and arranges elements .... it has 2event listeners on load and on resize..... on Desktop Mode Evrything works fine ok both load and resize ..... But When i swith to mobile type from dev tools all the elements that use innerWidth as a variable get disturbed ..... this mainly happened because i didn't set the width of an image to 100% of its cotainer wich allowed it to be at it's original size and overflow the innerWidth .... try to find elements that overflows the width of your viewport before js is loaded..... if you set a div with a width that is higher than your device width the innerWidth property gets disturbed ..... but only on mobile mode devtools the desktop mode works fine and im wondering if the problem is related to chrome devtools or the mobiles would really get the wrong innerwidth value ... after checking the element that causes the problem you can adjust its width directly from html css or set up its width with js before you start using the innerwidth property ... thus problem has confuded me and made me wanna launch automated tests because its unexpected and since i use the innerWidth a lot .... PS:Screenwidth will solve your problem but it will always get the screen size not the viewport size ... for mobiles and tablets thats going to work fine since they are always full screen but for desktop thats not going to work when you resize the browser window ... and maybe one day tabets and large mobile will allow users to resize their screens

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `window.innerWidth` property of Chromium-based browsers can get affected by the raw  width of embedded elements (e.g. hi-resolution images). The raw width is the width of the embedded elements before the CSS has been applied to the webpage and its content.

To prevent this, it is recommended to get the value of `window.innerWidth` and to store it in a variable **before** the content of the webpage (an thus the embedded elements) is loaded. To achieve this, place the javascript code refering to `window.innerWidth` before the content of the page in the HTML-file. In other words, place the content in `<script>`...`</script>` just after the `<body>`-tag.

Answer (score -1):

You should make a generic function.

```
    function paginate(array, page_size, page_number) {
     return array.slice((page_number - 1) * page_size, page_number * page_size);
    }
```

called this function whenever your screen size changes. First, try to get the data accordingly then fix the UI with CSS.

Comment: So the reason for this is that Google Chrome Dev Tools are showing me a different width number than console.log(window.innerWidth)